# Linux command line video editing

Tags: linux, video, command-line

I tried to google this for a while, but i didn't find anything relevant, so maybe someone here knows the answer:is there a way to add , dynamically, any text/effects/transitions from command line to a video?

Comment: If you are on Linux you can see some informations [here](http://superuser.com/questions/358082/command-line-video-editing-in-linux-cut-join-and-preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with FFmpeg using the `drawtext AVOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

FFMpeg (from http://ffmpeg.org/ ) maybe the right choice. You should give it a try.

Comment: i already tried ffmpeg, and will be useful for overlay , cut and join them. what i need is how to text to a video in a programmatic way